# Debugging Oracle DDL triggers

Tags: oracle, triggers, ddl-trigger

Can't understand why Oracle did not fire any DDL trigger.

```
>SELECT * FROM V$VERSION 
Oracle Database 18c Express Edition Release 18.0.0.0.0 - Production
```

Example from https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/lnpls/plsql-triggers.html#GUID-6CF3A208-0BE7-45FF-928C-A755526933D0

```
STUDENT> CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER drop_trigger
           BEFORE DROP ON student.SCHEMA
           BEGIN
             RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR (
               num => -20000,
               msg => 'Cannot drop object');
           END;
[2022-04-29 11:28:09] completed in 293 ms
STUDENT> create table  tbl1 (a integer)
[2022-04-29 11:28:16] completed in 124 ms
STUDENT> drop table tbl1
[2022-04-29 11:28:17] completed in 155 ms
```

user and schema - both "Student";

Absolutely the same with DDL-logging example from http://www.dba-oracle.com/sf_ora_04098_trigger_string_string_is_invalid_and_failed_re_validation.htm  - no any results for

```
after ddl on schema 
after ddl on student.schema 
after ddl on database   -- created from name of SYS user
```

All triggers a visible and shown as ENABLED at `all_triggers` .
There no problem-related message  at `user_errors` or `all_errors`

Any suggestion?

Comment: What is the purpose of this trigger? If you want to prevent the drop, then simply revoke the privilege for it.

Comment: I tried the trigger and it works, try to connect to the schema u want to put the trigger on and just write `before drop on schema` instead of `BEFORE DROP ON student.SCHEMA`.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit the privilege to drop objects cannot be revoked from the owner of the objects. Only the `DROP ALL ...` system-level privileges can be revoked., assuming they have been granted.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit "What is the purpose of this trigger?" - this is just example from documentation - it MUST work  but did not work

Comment: @toni-antunović for this and second example for question I have try all variants "ON SCHEMA", "ON name-of-schema.SCHEMA" and "ON DATABASE" -  same results - triggers present in all_triggers but still no effect

Comment: @potapuff Hard to help you when I cant replicate the problem, can you try to create the trigger on sys with `before drop on schema` and see if it works.

Comment: @ToniAntunović  can't do for SYS because of " ORA-30510: system triggers cannot be defined on the schema of SYS user" but "BEFORE DROP ON student.SCHEMA" -  from sys name has no effect . And "BEFORE DROP ON SCHEMA" from student name - same has no effect.

Comment: @potapuff Sorry I forgot about  ORA-30510, what I meant to ask you to try is that u create the trigger on a schema where u have all the privileges.

Comment: @ToniAntunović second part about that case. User "Student", schema "student",  And "BEFORE DROP ON SCHEMA" from student name - same has no effect.